# Mongoose - Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" at path _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the below schema:

```
var StorySchema = new Schema({
  title:        { type: String, required: true },
  users:        { 
                  id:        { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'users' },
                  creator:   { type: Boolean } 
                },       
  maxlines:     { type: Number, default: '10'},
  lines:        {
                  text:       { type: String },
                  entered_at: { type: Date }, 
                  user:       {
                                id:   { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'users' }
                              }
                },
  created_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }, 
  updated_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },        
})
```

I've got the below which does the query:

```
 exports.view = function (req, res) {  
    Stories
        .findOne({
            _id: req.params.id
        })
        /*.populate('users') */ **<-- If I uncomment this I get the error**
        .exec(function (err, story) {
            if (err) {
                res.json(200, {
                    success: "false",
                    message: err.message
                })
            } else if (story) {
                res.json({
                    sucess: "true",
                    message: story
                })
            } else {
                res.json(200, {
                    sucess: "false",
                    message: "story not found"
                })
            }
        })
}
```

As above if I add `.populate('users')` it flags the below error:

```
{
    "success": "false",
    "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"[object Object]\" at path \"_id\""
}
```

I'm calling /view/51fc2e02576f2dc058000001 (which is an Object ID of the stories table), without the `.populate('users')` if I call the URL it brings back the document.

The users -> id value is populated with `ObjectId("51fbe87ec137760025000001")` - which is a valid _id in the users collection

I cannot see what I'm missing?

**Added User Schema**

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name:                 { type: String, required: true },
  email:            { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  username:         { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  provider:         { type: String, required: true, enum: ['local', 'facebook']    },
  password:         { type: String, required: true },
  avatar:           { type: String, default: 'http://i.imgur.com/1PtcFos.jpg' },
  gender:           { type: String, required: true, uppercase: true, enum: ['M', 'F'] },
  facebook:         {
                 id:     { type: String }, 
                 token:   { type: String },
                 token_expiry: { type: Date }
                        },
  device:       {
                  token:        { type: String },
                  type:         { type: String, enum: ['ios', 'android'] },
                  badge:        { type: Number },
                  id:           { type: String },
                  created_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
                  updated_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
                },              
  created_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  updated_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }              
})
```

Comment: Can we see your user schema? Also, using a DBRef is pretty moot, I am not sure if mongoose will handle this as three requests or two -- you might want to look into that and then just `.findOne({_id: userIdOfMatching},fn(err,doc){..});` as a rule the populate method works by correctly matching the _id, which means you need to explicitly set the type to match that of the populated doc.

Comment: @David - I've added the user schema above, do the DBRef's not do anything? I thought it told mongoose which collection to look for the ID's?

Comment: and your creation line looks something like this: `Users = module.exports = db.model "users", UserSchema` ?

Comment: Yea i have `mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema)` and then `Users = mongoose.model('Users')` - The below suggestion from @sza seems to work when i use `.populate('users.id')

Comment: then your populate should be `.populate('Users')` and not `.populate('users')` -- try that and see how she does. It'd be easy enough for mongoose toLowerCase() this, but I'm not sure that they do, if it's the solution I may `lul`

Comment: Tried `.populate('Users')` no luck just brings back the document with the ID

Comment: how about changing the `{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'users' }` to match `{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Users' }`?

Comment: `.populate('Users.id')` doesn't work either, it seems to only like `.populate('users.id')`

The schema is actually `{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Users' }` it's showing as 'users' above because i copied it when i was testing if it was due to the case

Comment: Looking at mongoDB the actual collection is called users rather than Users

Comment: so the `.populate('users.id')` is working, your Schema name is valid (you've verified)? I wonder if it's because you're using `id` in your schema already it needs some additional help, from their docs `Story.find(...).populate('fans').populate('author').exec()` should work..?

Comment: Yea `.populate('users.id')` appears to be working, the schema is referenced as Users everywhere, but I checked the actual collection on mongolab its called users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can only do `.populate('users.id')`. [Populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) is to use the reference Object to replace the `id` field. Please take a look at the doc.

Comment: this isn't correct, you can chain in multiple populates as well, `.populate('user someOtherDoc andAnotherDoc')` you identify in the schema what it is to match, and it only supports document `_id` ie: `{type: Schema.ObjectId, rel: "user"}` which tells mongoose that you're looking for an `_id` inside of the "user" schema thats type is `Schema.ObjectId`, if you had a 0-1 index for your `_id` your could then do `{type: Number ..}` or if you had a string you could do `{type: String ..}` and etc, cheers.

Comment: Correct, but I don't think it can apply to an sub document, currently  `users` contains an object rather than a field.

Comment: Correct, sub collections can't be populated as they are by default, and I'm not sure you can even populate into them from other collections?